# How to make NSURL variable is nil when parsed from null String?

Tags: ios, nsurl

I'm a newbie in iOS development. Sometimes my API server returns a `nil` value. This is raising an error when I try to create a `NSURL` instance.

Here is the condition:

```
NSString *tmpURL = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:tmpURL];
```

In this condition, it will make the app crash. I just want to make the `url` variable nil, not raise an error.

Comment: If Jelle's answer helped you solve your problem (i think it should) please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *tmpURL = nil;
NSURL *url = tmpUrl ? [NSURL URLFromString:tmpURL] : nil;
```