# What is the correct syntax to convert an Objective-C / iOS string to URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am getting an error at:

```
[cardView setOnWeb:[NSURL URLFromString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
```

The error message says, "No known class field for selector 'URLFromString'."

As far as I can tell from [How to make NSURL variable is nil when parsed from null String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969856/how-to-make-nsurl-variable-is-nil-when-parsed-from-null-string), the poster was able (except in the nil case he asked about) to use the basic syntax of `[NSURL URLFromString:tmpURL]`.

So what do I need to change here?

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get NSURL from NSString, use below

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:yourString];
```

In your case, it would be

```
[cardView setOnWeb:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you; will accept in 10 minutes.